# MVC3 Managing Remote Validation Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation, remote-validation

i have the following problem:
i'm using remote validation for validate a field and now i'm trying to manage exception

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>() { "AAAA", "BBBB" }; //blacklist

    public JsonResult NameAllowed(string ID)
    {
        throw new Exception();
        //return Json(!values.Contains(ID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

but in this case the form wasn't submitted (ERROR 500 through network capturing, dev toolbar) and doesn't appear any error.

1. What is the best way to manage exception (for example Timeout and
   not predictable exceptions)?
2. Exist a solution (any server side parameter) to skip these errors for submit the form?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote validation should ONLY be used as a graphical feedback to the client that prevents the user from sending useless data to the server. You should **ALWAYS** have a server side validation for everything you have to validate, and if you do, well, your form will be sent but not approved, and your validation error will be displayed along with a re-rendered form with your invalid inputs.

Take client side / remote validation as a "Pre-Validation" that has 2 purpose

1. Prevent useless server-side processing
2. Give a more responsive validation of data instead of waiting for the form to be submited.

They should however never be used to actually validate the data.

**Edit**

That said, how about just writing your validation code properly, using try catches and not letting any unhandle exception slip throught?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have see already the solution mentioned by you, with try catches, but is the best practice? Did you have some articles that give some guidelines? (not msdn, i have already followed the tutorial, but these informations are missing)

Comment: Best practice should involve fixing your code to prevent throwing exceptions. This, sometimes, involves Try Catches. However, I have a feeling that, for a remote validator, you shouldn't need try catchs. Theres something in your validation action that could be written in a better way. But try catches are always a good thing to have if well implemented.